# Created a new Active Record model in controller but it doesn't show up on view unless I refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the controller, specifically the edit action, I created a new Active Record model in the same manner as this:

```
@newPost = Post.new
@newPost.update_attribute(:title, @some_title)
@newPost.update_attribute(:completed, 0)
@newPost.save

@all_user_posts = @user.posts
```

Now, when I try to call on @all_user_posts and show it in the view, it doesn't show up unless I refresh the page. What's going on here and is there a better way to approach this so that I can show the new posts as soon as I create them without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I can actually just do this:

```
@all_user_posts = Post.where("user_id =?", @user.id)
```

But, could someone still explain why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that before you created new post, you did sth like

```
@user = User.find(parmas[:id])
```

This means that object has been loaded to a memory and assign to a variable. When you created a post (btw, where do you assign it to user?) the object loaded from the database is not being reloaded again, but it is being used as it seats in memory (it's cached).

This should work:

```
@all_user_posts = @user.posts(true)
```

This will force reloading the association.

One more important note: do never ever use update_attribute method because:
  1. It is saving an object (that's not really the issue with this method, just it is worth knowing it)
  2. It skips validations!

Instead use assign_attributes method, which accepts hash of attributes and do not save an object. But since you are saving it, you can also use update_attributes method (mind the "s" at the end) which literally runs assign_attributes and then save the record (3 lines in one, yey!).
You can go even further and use create method on Post class, which 
  1. Create new object
  2. Assign_attributes with passed hash
  3. Saves the object (not skipping validations)

So top 4 lines might be written in one:

```
@newPost = Post.create(:title => @some_title, :completed => 0)
```

Another point: mind the ruby naming convention. There should be @new_post

And last one: are you really using all of those variables (@newPost, @some_title, @user and @all_user_posts) inside a view. If not, there is no need to add @ sign in front of them. Also I am not sure what do you need @all_user_posts variable, you can simply use @user.posts in your view.

Comment: Note that I said I created something "in a similar manner" to this. I actually don't have any "Posts" or "Users" for my app. No need to worry about that part; these are just random lines of code made up for an explanation. I'll test out the @user.posts(true) though. Thanks!